# How make hierarchy of friend classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have `class A` which has only private members (inclusive data, methods, constructors, destructor .... ). Also I have `class B` which is friend of `class A`. And I want all derived classes of B (also there are templates which are inherited from B) to be friends of `class A` too. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Make the members `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Because I don't want other classes expect B(and deriveds) could create and manage instances of A type.

Comment: @Billy, will that work? Making them private will allow access to A's derived classes, not to B's (friend's).

Comment: @Sergey: I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Sergey: You are write Billys suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't support this directly: ["a kid of my friend is not my friend"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.4).

You have to use another way to implement this; for example, define a set of protected accessor functions in `class B`:

```
class A {friend class B; int x, y};

class B
{
protected:
    int& AccessX(A& a) {return a.x;}
    int& AccessY(A& a) {return a.y;}
}
```

This is only feasible if `class A` is very small.

If `class A` is large, you will have to think what exactly you want `class B` and its derived classes to do with `class A`, and express it as a set of functions. Define these as protected functions in `class B`:

```
class A
{
    A(): x(42), y(99) {}
    friend class B;
    int x, y;
}

class B
{
protected:
    A Create() {return A();}
    void Manage(A& object) {object.x += 1; object.y += 2;}
}
```

Comment: It would make sense to make access functions static as they don't use anything in the class B.